# Image Resizer installation not working (even resizer.debug)

Tags: iis, iis-8, imageresizer

I tried to install ImageResizer on a Windows Server 2012 RC2 with IIS 8.5 but I have no error message and it doesn't work. I can't reach the debugging page : resizer.debug.ashx

I tried to install the bare minimum on my test server to test it and eventually buy the creative license.

What I did so far :

- Create a folder bin with the imageresizer.dll
- Add the default web.config in the download
- Read documentation : https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/troubleshoot and https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/geterror.
- Create a virtual folder with my images
- Give permissions to the application pool identity to the virtual folder

I succeedeed to install this on my development computer. I probably missing something to install in my IIS configuration...

It was so easy to install on my computer, but I have a hard time to make it work on my server...

Thanks for helping me...

Comment: Sorry! It wasn't related to ImageResizer.  I didn't give the NTFS permissions (application pool user : IIS AppPool\[application_pool])  to some files. Shame on me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Martin [answered his own question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986798/image-resizer-installation-not-working-even-resizer-debug#comment73087210_42986798) but may not have the points to create a matching answer.

The application pool user account needs NTFS read/write/delete permissions to the the ~/imagecache directory and at least read permissions to the application folder.